# Zram does not start at start-up

Tags: swap, zram

I am using pinguyos 11.10. Pinguyos is a variant of Ubuntu 11.10.

I have installed zram like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/zram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zramswap-enabler
```

But zram doesnot start automatically upon startup. I have to manually say: `service zramswap start` to make it start. Before and after enabling zramswap manually `free` gives this:

Before:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2061184    1165240     895944          0      31632     559816
-/+ buffers/cache:     573792    1487392
Swap:            0          0          0
```

After:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2061184    1217888     843296          0      33136     567232
-/+ buffers/cache:     617520    1443664
Swap:      2061176          0    2061176
```

And I have no physical swap partitions enabled.. so does this make any difference?
Is a swap partition necessary for zramswap to work?

P.S Until I start the service manually, there is no `zram0`,`zram1` in `/dev`
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Pinguyos is not an offical Ubuntu derivative, so therefore your question does not belong on Ask Ubuntu. It should be moved to the Unix and Linux StackExchange, which is accessible through Unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo gedit /etc/init.d/rc.local` and modify the file to contain your `service zramswap start` command. This should run the command at the end of the boot process.

Comment: Thanks, after adding the service zramswap start to rc.local.. it worked.. :) but still wondering why the script from ppa didnt do this first hand??

Comment: I'm not sure, did you do what was specified in [this](http://weirdfellow.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/compressed-ram-with-zram/) link? If you did, it should have worked, but it may have had a bug or something.